# How to load data into TableView of one MPart, by selecting one child of TreeViewer from other Mpart

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4

I have simple requirement : My application contain 2 MParts. One MPart contains list of IDs displayed in TreeView from Database. By clicking on any ID, another MPart should populate/display data related to slected ID (from DB) in TableView.

I written, 1st MPart and it is displaying IDs in TreeView. On click capturing user selected ID and retrieved data related to that ID from DB. Using EPartService, i got reference of 2nd MPart. But not able to modify its TableView. (initially, i populated this TableView with empty rows. default). Basically I am trying to modify 2nd Mpart from 1st Mpart.

I am beginner, tried all related posts available in the net. Please point me right direction

Comment: can you please show us your code?

Answer (score 0):

When you have the `MPart` for the table view you can call `getObject()` to get your view class:

```java
MPart tableViewPart = ....

MyTableView view = (MyTableView)tableViewPart.getObject();

// TODO call some method of MyTableView to set the table
```

where `MyTableView` is the class you defined for the view part in the Application.e4xmi.

Note: If the part has not yet been shown the object will be null. Use `EPartService.showPart` to show the part and create the object.

Comment: Thanks Greg, i tried this earlier but not working. Please find my code, seems I am doing some silly mistake.

Comment: Thanks Greg, i tried this earlier but not working. Please find my code, seems I am doing some silly mistake.     MPart vp = partService.findPart("vp"); // Getting refenrece here
 InfoPart ip = (InfoPart)vp.getObject(); // vp.getObject(); returning null
 TableViewer tv = ip.getViewer();
 tv.setInput(mi);

Comment: If the part has not already been shown the object will not have been created yet - use `EPartService.showPart` to show the part and create the object.

Comment: On load (first time) InfoPart is loaded with TableView with blank spaces. Then user is allowed to select ID in TreeView to render TableView from ID details. I tried calling EPartService.showPart(vp, PartState.ACTIVATE) after building blank space TableView. also tried by putting same statement  before InfoPart ip = (InfoPart)vp.getObject();

Answer (score 0):

In the following answer I will asume that you are talking about JFace `TreeViewer` and `TableViewer`. If you are talking about JavaFX `TreeView` and `TableView` you will need to use a different way of capturing the selection event, but the usage of the `ESelectionService` remains the same.

**Setting the Selection**

In the part with the tree you can use dependency injection to get the `ESelectionService`

```
@Inject private ESelectionService selectionService;
```

You can then add a `ISelectionChangedListener` to the `TreeViewer` and forward the selection to the selection service.

```
ISelectionChangedListener selectionListener = new ISelectionChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {
        IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) event.getSelection();
        selectionService.setSelection(selection);
    }
};
treeView.addSelectionChangedListener(selectionListener);
```

Instead of pushing the `IStructuredSelection` to the context you could also use your ID directly, i.e. by using `selection.getFirstElement()`.

**Observing the Selection**

In the part with the table showing the details you can have the current selection injected. This method will be called everytime the selection changes.

```
@Inject
public void setSelection(@Named(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_SELECTION) @Optional Object selection) {
    // process the selection
}
```

Note the use of `@Optional` here. This will ensure that the method is also called when the active selection is `null`.

**More Information**

For more information on the `ESelectionService` please refer to this tutorial:
http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/tutorials/eclipse-4-e4-tutorial-part-7-services/

Comment: Thanks Christoph, solution is perfectly fit to my requirement. I am able to update TableView based on ID selection in TreeView. But not able see updated TableView with data in MPart, seems MPart/TableView is not refreshing. Any pointers on it ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You can "update the TableView" but the "MPart/TableView is not refreshing"? Edit the question and show us your code please.